# ROS Answers SE migration: View in Rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rrbot_rviz.launch] is neither a launch file in package [rrbot_description] nor is [rrbot_description] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219726/view-in-rviz/) by [M imran](https://answers.ros.org/users/23352/m-imran/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-10-23

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seem like you did not sourced the workspace or package path is not valid.

You may try `source /home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` . If this does not help please check package path.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3